# Animate jQuery - Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate an element that is within a iframe.

```
$("#Browser").contents().find("#mouse").animate({top:"10px"},500)
```

I seem to be getting this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'cur' of undefined
```

Comment: may be because of "Access Denied" error?check this : alert($("#Browser").contents().find("#mouse").length) and see what is the length...

Comment: ok, it say that founded the object, now you shoukld to test another method for it for example $("#Browser").contents().find("#mouse").hide() and check work or not, if it work then problem is in your jquery resource

Comment: i can change the value with '$("#Browser").contents().find("#mouse"). css("top","10x")' just can't seem to animate

Comment: hiding the object worked

Comment: ok, what version of jquery do you use?change it to a higher version

Comment: Thank you. I changed my jQuery resource to **jQuery-2.1.1.js** rather than **jQuery-1.9.1.js** and it worked.

Comment: your welcome, plz mark as usefull if it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with your {top:"10px"} part. If you do this you should try using:

```
    $("#Browser").contents().find("#mouse").animate({top:10px;},500);
```